# Get Submitted Data from Blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, database

I'm using a html code connected to my smart contract via testrpc node, where users submit temperature data.

How can I view that data from the smart contract, each time I view from the contract I see the last data entry not all entries?

How can I see all?

Comment: Did you store your data in array? If no, then use an array to store the data and return the whole to get all data.

Comment: Was thinking of doing so. However, arent there any other way?

Comment: Alternative way might be searching for events in the blockchain. You should have event emitted when adding each data. Collect all of your data entry events, parse and show them.

Comment: I do have an event when users input the data, but dont know how to parse all of those events and show them.

Comment: @user51821 This might be helpful for you to getting past events: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents